# Adding text to the beginning of a text file without having to copy the entire file in R

Tags: r

I have many large text files, and I would like to add a line at the very beginning. I saw someone had asked this already [here](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Appending-strings-at-the-beginning-of-a-text-file-td901370.html). However, this involves reading the entire text file and appending it to the single line. Is there a better (faster) way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested this on windows 7 and it works. Essentially, you use the `shell` function and do everything on the windows `cmd` which is quite fast.

```
write_beginning <- function(text, file){

  #write your text to a temp file i.e. temp.txt
  write(text, file='temp.txt')
  #print temp.txt to a new file 
  shell(paste('type temp.txt >' , 'new.txt'))
  #append your file to new.txt
  shell(paste('type', file, '>> new.txt'))
  #remove temp.txt - I use capture output to get rid of the 
  #annoying TRUE printed by file.remove
  dump <- capture.output(file.remove('temp.txt'))
  #uncomment the last line below to rename new.txt with the name of your file
  #and essentially modify your old file
  #dump <- capture.output(file.rename('new.txt', file))
}

#assuming your file is test.txt and you want to add 'hello' at the beginning just do:
write_beginning('hello', 'test.txt')
```

On linux you just need to find the corresponding command in order to send a file to another one (I really think you need to replace `type` by `cat` on linux but I cannot test right now).

Comment: Thanks. I did not know about shell

Comment: You are very welcome. It is a very useful function :)

Answer (score 0):

You'd use the system() function on a Linux distro:

```
system('cp file.txt temp.txt; echo " " > file.txt; cat temp.txt >> file.txt; rm temp.txt')
```